# Which way is major in this interesting intramolecular SN2 reaction to form different five memeber ring?

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, regioselectivity, intramolecular-reaction

Which direction of the intramolecular reactions is major and why? Could someone could depict the mechanism step by step and it is better to draw out the transitional state configurations

[image: Reaction scheme]

Comment: The two lone pairs are obviously not equivalent. Any stabilization would lead to decreased nucleophilicity. Can you identify any factors that might stabilize two lone pairs?

Comment: @Zhe Can you elaborate a little more? I am not exactly sure about the factor you're referring to, is it the conjugation between both the oxygens?

Comment: I want to know what the difference between these two lone pairs was, and could anybody sketch out the molecular orbitals of these two lone pairs located in?